# Is git diff --staged same as git diff --cached HEAD?

Tags: git, diff

Is `git diff --staged` same as `git diff --cached HEAD`?

By the way, `git diff --cached` is the same as `git diff --cached HEAD` here.

Thanks.

Comment: Note: I removed the [tag:caching] tag as Git's index / staging-area / cache is not what the tag is really for...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `git diff`, `--staged` and `--cached` are synonyms: use whichever you like.

Omitting `HEAD` generally implies the same thing as `HEAD`, so these are *almost* 100% identical, but there is one exception: in a new repository that has *no* commits yet, `git diff --staged` works and `git diff --staged HEAD` does not:

```
$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   README.md

$ git diff --cached
diff --git a/README.md b/README.md
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..9daeafb
--- /dev/null
+++ b/README.md
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+test
$ git diff --cached HEAD
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

(This is because `git diff --[cached|staged]` is clever enough to notice that `HEAD` is invalid, and to diff against the [empty tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765453/1256452) instead.  If you type in `HEAD` yourself, though, `git diff` dutifully attempts to resolve it to a commit hash ID, which then fails, producing the above error.)

(This exception also applies when creating an orphan branch, which is functionally very similar to this initial-empty-repository state: the special `HEAD` file holds the name of a branch that does not exist, so `HEAD` itself is only valid when being resolved as a branch name, not when being resolved as a commit hash ID.)